# Plugins for adding mathematical equation in tinyMCE editor?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce, latex

I've been working on Ruby on Rails project, trying to integrate Latex plugin to TinyMCE.

WIRIS plugin doesn't work properly, have spent long time try to resolve problems but still not working. And some other plugins are outdated and doesn't support the latest tinyMCE version.

Is there any suggestion plugin to do this?

Comment: Please provide us more details of the issue you are experiencing at support@wiris.com. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So just want to help people who've struggled over this too. I finally found one nice Equation editor plugin: http://latex.codecogs.com/eqneditor/integration/tinymce_v4/install.php
which is very intuitive and easy to integrate.

The download link in the text doesn't work, have to click on the pic at upperright.
Make sure you add to your assets/javascripts/application.js path to tinymce/plugins/eqneditor and should be good to go!